# What is the advantage of "!important" with CSS?

Tags: css

I'm working on a code of someone else and noticed that he used a lot of "!important" within the CSS. It has been used also for font-family which I don't understand the reason for. Is this really need or more a mistake of the previous programmer?

Can someone please explain me when to use "!important" and for what it's good for?

Thanks

Comment: Google "!important css", first result - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: It's good for almost nothing.

Comment: @Zenith Thanks for the link. It's informative and the argue about the author's CSS funny to read... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!important` makes a css attribute take precedence over any other which that selector applies. For instance, in the following `.something` would have a 5px border despite there being a declaration after the 5px one:

```
.something{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.something{
        border: 5px solid red !important;
}

.something{
        border: 2px solid red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hDWkG/) to show the example.

If you remove `!important` the box would have a 2px border.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply and the example, I guess I've got the point now. Since I did already some corrections to the stylesheet I was working on, I will re-check and remove all the "!important" which are actually not need anymore.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) :

> an "!important" declaration (the delimiter token "!" and keyword "important" follow the declaration) takes precedence over a normal declaration.

When two style rules are the same, it gives the one marked `!important` greater importance while applying styles.